# Why can't I project from view?

Tags: texturing

So, I am making a tree but when I select the trunk ( a cube with vertices all merged together to form a trunk ) but when I try to project it from view ( I have selected all of the vertices ), the button turns grey and I can't press it. Please help.
Picture of the button: [image: As you can see, the button is grey]

This is all the vertices of the tree:
[image: the vertices]

Comment: Hello, it may be because you don't have any faces in your topology, only edges?

Comment: Yes, you need to apply the skin modifier first. Alternatively if you want it to stay editable you can use a UV Project modifier

Comment: how do i apply the skin modifier @Gorgious

Comment: In the modifier tab on the right, click on the dropdown arrow between the camera icon and the X icon and choose "apply modifier"